# How can I wait an element to be clickable?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have the next situation in the React Application:
test.js:

```
describe('TEST', async () => {
before(() => {
    cy.makeLogin();
});

it('test', () => {
    cy.intercept('/login').as('makeLogin')
    //.wait(2000);

    cy.get("li:contains('New')")
        .should('be.visible')
        .trigger('mouseover'); // 1st moment

    cy.get('.ant-menu-sub').find("li:contains('Part 1')").click();

    cy.get('.ant-upload-drag')
        .should('be.visible')
        .attachFile(['images/large4x.png'], { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
        .should('be.visible')
        //.wait(2000); 

    cy.get('.status-icon > span').should('have.attr', 'style', 'color: rgb(82, 196, 26);') 
    // 2nd moment
})
})
```

Command.js :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('makeLogin', () => {
  ... command description ...
  });
});
```

At the 1st moment, I need to use the .wait(2000) command. Because Those elements aren't clickable without the wait method.
At the 2nd moment, the color doesn't change while IMG is downloaded.

By the way, I set different timeouts in the cypress.config.js:

```
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  defaultTimeout: 30000,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 40000,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  responseTimeout: 60000,
  timeout: 60000
```

But it isn't operating without wait.
What can I do to execute this test case without wait?

Comment: what does your 'makeLogin' command do?

Comment: You have placed your intercept too late in the sequence, set it up at the top before `cy.makelogin()` and at the beginning of the test ***wait*** for it - `cy.wait('@makeLogin')`.

Comment: @jjhelguero makeLogin signes in as user cypress

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR thnx, your recommendation is valid

Comment: and what can I do with 2nd moment? It is after downloading

Comment: Is it a React app?

Comment: @Fody Yes, It is React app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React apps based on hooks (functional components) I've found they something need Cypress to release the execution thread to complete an async operation, e.g to finish `useEffect()` processing.

There is no `sleep()` command in Cypress, but the equivalent is `cy.wait(0)`. It does not wait, but releases the execution thread to the Javascript running in the app.

Immediately the app is finished, control comes back to to test. Now assertions can pass because the DOM is in the expected state.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.intercept('/login').as('makeLogin')
  cy.makeLogin();
});

it('test', () => {
  cy.wait('@makeLogin')

  cy.get("li:contains('New')")
    .should('be.visible')
    .trigger('mouseover'); // 1st moment

  cy.get('.ant-menu-sub').find("li:contains('Part 1')").click();

  cy.get('.ant-upload-drag')
    .should('be.visible')
    .attachFile(['images/large4x.png'], { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
    .should('be.visible')

  // allow app to process upload
  cy.wait(0)

  cy.get('.status-icon > span')
    .should('have.attr', 'style', 'color: rgb(82, 196, 26);')   
})
```

Comment: thnx, I understand this case. But, .wait(0) is a very small value, my code needs 1500-2000. How can I do it by another way?

Comment: If `.wait(0)` does not work, then the app is not being blocked (it was was just a hunch). Something must trigger the color change. Perhaps the server sends back a response after upload. If you find that (in devtools Network tab) you can add another intercept (before `.attachFile()`) and wait on that (after `.attachFile()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{timeout:60000}` this waits element to load and then will click to the button

```
cy.get("button", {timeout: 60000})
 .should("be.visible")
 .click()
```

Comment: I set timeout:60000 at the cypress.config.js. This doesn't operate